# SFX installer fails to run powershell script after powershell window is opened

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I am creating an 7zip sfx installer in latest Windows 10 which is expected to run a powershell script. when extraction is done, the powershell window is shown up but quickly closed without executing the script.

Any help is much appreciated!

I have tried to sign the script file and the installer.exe itself with self signed certificate, but no luck.

I have changed the Powershell ExecutionPolicy to Unrestricted for all scopes for troubleshooting, but no luck either

I use process monitor in sysinternals to capture the powershell.exe behavor, and found powershell starts to exit thread after reading and writing c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\StartupProfileData-Interactive

Here is my config.txt for 7zip sfx:

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="Cloud API"
BeginPrompt="Do you want to install Cloud API?"
RunProgram="powershell.exe -NoExit –NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %%T\\cloud_api\\installer.PS1"
Directory="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

I am zipping the files in python by:

```sh
..\\7zr a -sfx7zSD.sfx cloud-api.7z .\\cloud-api -r -y
```

I am expecting the installer.PS1 getting executed after unzipping, but only powershell.exe is run and exit quickly without running the script at all.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the full path to the `.ps1` file? Also consider putting `pause` at the end of the script. If it is actually getting called, the PS window that opens should pause before closing.

Comment: Thank you@root for your help. I just double checked the path of installer.PS1 and found it is wrong. After I corrected it, it got executed as expected. Could you please add your comment as an answer for me to confirm?Thanks again!

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first step to troubleshooting this problem would be to declare the full path of the `.ps1` script in your 7zip config. This will ensure you are calling the script you intend to launch.

Comment: I tried the full path to the script file.  It did not work.
The powershell script is one of the files in the 7Z exe.  It appears as if the 7Zip EXE is attempting to run the command before it extracts the files.  When the execution is completed, I have no files in the folder in which I ran the exe.

Per the documentation, the %%T is supposed to be the temporary folder to where the files are extracted.